# Flutter: get provider or context in a Service class?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am fairly new to flutter, so I may be going the wrong way about this. Basically, I need to authenticate the user at the beginning and I will get a token that I use as Bearer for every post/put/get request.

I created an AuthProvider that logs in the user and gets a token.

My problem is now: how do I get this token when I am already logged in and want to fire a new put request? I created a UserRepository.dart class, where I want to handle all the user requests.

```
class UserRepository {
  Future<bool> doSomething(string dataString) async {
    String bearer = "xxx"; // how do I get this? 
    var bd = await http.put(
      Uri.parse(BASE_URL + 'foo/bar'),
      headers: <String, String>{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + bearer
    );
    return false;
  }
}
```

now in a widget I would get my bearer like this:

```
AuthProvider provider = Provider.of(context, listen: false);
var bearer = await provider.getAccessToken();
```

the problem is, I dont have the context in my UserRepository. So how do I do this, because when using a repository somewhere in a widget I do not always want to pass the context or the accesstoken to it - there has to be a better way, right?

Comment: so how would you do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Send the token from the view to the service class by parameter in the function you invoke.

Like this : `ApiService.getStudents(context.read<Auth>().token);`